# Enum extension method to get all values

Tags: c#

I want to do something like this:

```
enum MyEnum { None, One, Two };

var myEnumValues = MyEnum.Values();
```

My extension method:

```
        public static IEnumerable<T> Values<T>(this Enum enumeration)
             where T : struct
         => Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
```

But it looks this way:

```
MyEnum.None.Values<MyEnum>();
```

How to do it?

Comment: You could remove *one* part of this by using `this object value`, and removing the `<T>` and then using `.GetType()` and so on on that value, but you can't get rid of the `None` in `MyEnum.None`. That's just a limitation of extension methods.

Comment: You could also use `this T enumeration` instead to remove the need to specify the generic type.

Comment: You would probably be better off with just naming the class and method appropriately, so you would get something like `EnumValues.Of<MyEnum>()`

Comment: `var myEnumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).OfType<MyEnum>();`

Answer (score 4):

Extension methods are static methods that are applied to an instance of an object.

`MyEnum` is a type, and not an instance, so you can't add extension methods to it.

Answer (score 0):

How about such a construct? It mimics the way enum is working, but it has a possibility to implement the `Values` method:

```
public class WeatherType
{
    private readonly string name;

    public static readonly WeatherType Bad = new WeatherType("Bad");
    public static readonly WeatherType Good = new WeatherType("Good");
    public static readonly WeatherType Mid = new WeatherType("Mid");

    private static readonly WeatherType[] Values = { Bad, Good, Mid };

    public static WeatherType[] GetValues()
    {
        return (WeatherType[])Values.Clone();
    }

    private WeatherType(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

You now has a static method to get a list of possible values, like this:

```
var values = WeatherType.GetValues();
```